# Get number order of div by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code :

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<input type="button" class="button" value="get number">
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wudaG, i need when click on `button` alert me the number order of div , that's mean in this code number `4`.

Comment: `the number order of div` -- which one of six?

Comment: What is `the number order`? total number of `div`s (I can see 6)? A `div` containing `4` (I can't see one)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$('.button').on('click', function (){
    $(this).index() + 1; // add one since index is zero-based
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wudaG/1/

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $(this).index()++;
});
```

Comment: You can't assign a value to a function call, this will cause a `ReferenceError`: http://jsfiddle.net/wudaG/5/